# Web Authentication with client certification

Tags: asp.net, authentication, x509certificate

I'm trying to authenticate login of a web app with three elements:

- Userid of web app
- Password of web app
- Client Certificates installed on user's PC. I see a client or machine certificate as a long string or key which is stored in Windows registry.

I'm planning to put those three elements together in a table, so when user intent to login, it will send those three elements to server side and they will be checked.

For example, if user loads web app in a PC which has not be assigned to him, then server will validate that userid and password are correct, but client certificate does not belong to user, and will reject login.

I haven't yet installed a client or machine certificate in every client PC nor installed a CA in IIS. But according to [Microsoft](https://forums.asp.net/p/2052070/5915706.aspx?Re%20Web%20Authentication%20using%20machine%20or%20client%20certificates), an asp.net web app will send automatically a client or machine certificate to server and asp.net can get it. Also I have found another [program example](http://www.techques.com/question/1-867171/read-client-certificate-from-httprequest-C) for doing that.

How is that possible? I allways thought that an asp.net web app can't read client resources and if you want to read client resources, then you should use something like ActiveX with all its complications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your are right, ASP.NET can't read any client resources. ASP.NET has nothing to do with getting a client certificate from the the user's PC.

What you do is to tell your Web Server (IIS) to request or require a client certificate. The server is adding a special http header to tell the browser to send a client certificate. The Browser asks Windows for one, or uses its own store (Firefox). The browser then sends the public part of the client certificate to the server.

Your ASP.NET can ask IIS whether the browser has sent a certificate and access that information for authentication purposes.